# Removing rows from a dataframe based on another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have one dataframe A that contains a list of countries:

```
Country
Hong Kong
Ireland
Thailand
```

There are more elements than that but I will just use three for now.

I also have another dataframe B where:

```
Country_Name      ID
France            3
France            NA
Japan             7
Korea             1
Hong Kong         18
Indonesia         NA
Japan             NA
Hong Kong         53
```

What I'm trying to do now is, to **compare the list of Country** in **dataframe B** with that of **dataframe A.**

If a **country in dataframe B** is **not listed in dataframe A**, and the **ID column is not NA**, then **it is preserved**, otherwise **it is removed**. Therefore, the resulting dataframe is:

```
Country_Name      ID
France            3
Japan             7
Korea             1
Hong Kong         18
Hong Kong         53
```

**France** has **two rows** in **dataframe B**, and since **France is not in dataframe A**,  then if there **exist any row in which France has NA in it's ID** column, it is **removed**. **Hong Kong is present** in dataframe A, hence it will still **remain.**

I tried something like:

```
df_B[!df_B$Country_Name %in% df_A$Country & !na.omit(df_B$ID),]
```

But the problem is that Hong Kong will get omitted in the resulting dataframe.

Comment: Can you please make this a question with reproducible example? :)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `na.omit`, we need `is.na` as `is.na` returns a logical vector while `na.omit` removes the `NA` elements creating a difference in `length`

```
df_B[df_B$Country_Name %in% df_A$Country|(!df_B$Country_Name %in% df_A$Country & !is.na(df_B$ID)),]
```

---

Or use `subset`

```
subset(df_B, Country_Name %in% df_A$Country|
       !(Country_Name %in% df_A$Country) & !is.na(ID))
#  Country_Name ID
#1       France  3
#3        Japan  7
#4        Korea  1
#5    Hong Kong 18
#8    Hong Kong 53
```

#### data

```
df_A <- structure(list(Country = c("Hong Kong", "Ireland", "Thailand"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df_B <- structure(list(Country_Name = c("France", "France", "Japan", 
"Korea", "Hong Kong", "Indonesia", "Japan", "Hong Kong"), ID = c(3L, 
NA, 7L, 1L, 18L, NA, NA, 53L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the `dplyr` version. A little longer to write, but easier (IMO) to read:

```
library(tidyverse)

df_B %>%
    filter(!is.na(ID)) %>% # keep rows where ID is not NA
    anti_join(df_A, by = c("Country_Name" = "Country")) # remove rows that are not in df_A
```